# Creating a time-sensitive Keyboard Shortcut Chord with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using the following script to run a bunch of commands when pressing Ctrl-Alt-I and then following with a key of p, k or u. How can I change this to wait like 2 seconds for the next key, or otherwise just send Ctrl-Alt-I and stop waiting on the next key

```
^!i::
Input key, I L1
IfEqual key,p
   Run, "C:\Temp"
IfEqual key,k
   Run, "C:\Temp\1"
IfEqual key,u
   Run, "C:\Temp\2"
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
$^!i::
    Input key1, I L1 T2 ;wait 2 seconds for a keypress
    If (key1 = "p" || key1 = "k" || key1 = "u") { ;if p, k or u were pressed
        If (key1 = "p") { ;if the first key we waited for was p:
            Run, "C:\Temp"
        } Else If (key1 = "k") { ;if the first key we waited for was k:
            Run, "C:\Temp\1"
        } Else If (key1 = "u") { ;if the first key we waited for was u:
            Run, "C:\Temp\2"
        } Else {
            SendInput, ^!i
        }
    }
Return
```

Comment: I don't know.. this didn't really work ... It seems to be stuck on the return forever...
016: Return (3.46)
045: Input,key1,I L1 T0.3 (0.33)
046: if (key1 = "p" || key1 = "k" || key1 = "u")  
060: Return (13.24)

Press [F5] to refresh.

Comment: I tried renaming key1 to key2 in the various ifs where you check for p k and u . but it still doesn't work. Also increased key 2 time to 2 secs and nothing

Comment: You need to release control, alt and i before pressing your next two keys. Keyboards aren't really built to handle that many keypresses at the same time. And the script doesn't get stuck. If you don't believe me, put a MsgBox in the beginning of your hotkey and you'll see.

Comment: I have added a msgbox and it gets up to this line: 
        Input key2, I L1 T2 ;wait 2 seconds for another key to get pressed. PS: I am not hitting Ctrl-Alt-I-p all at the same time. I first press Ctrl-Alt-I and release, then I press p. Have you run this script yourself?

Comment: So you don't want to wait "for the next key" after pressing p? Okay, I removed that part from the script. Try again. Yes, I tested it before posting, well that is, the first version I posted.

Comment: This is better, it responds to my following key press 'p' or 'k', but how do I send it the original "^!i" if nothing is pressed? Do I just put an else { Send, ^!i } ?

Comment: I think the else needs to be outside of the first if statement. I'm noticing that it might be looping, the minute you send ^!i, it starts at the procedure again waiting for a following key stroke, is it possible to send this input without auto-hokey interceding it?

Comment: Ah just tried Send, ^!i and it seems to have worked.

Comment: I'd go with SendInput though. It's way more reliable and faster than Send in my experience.

Comment: If the hotkey triggers itself put a dollar sign in front of your hotkey. `$^!i::` That prevents the hotkey from triggering itself.